# ActionSheet Throws Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I'm using [Action Sheet Picket](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker). I added .h and .m files as instructed in readme, picker and even `cancelAction` is working well but somehow `successAction` throws `NSInvalidArgumentException` with this message: "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Application is a kind of tab bar application with `Navigation Controller`. There is a `TabBarController` as root and there are `ViewController`s which are located under the `TabBarController` and one of the ViewControllers is a Navigation Controller. But I'm not getting this error in Navigation Controller. I'm not sure if this causes any error.

Here how I used:

```
- (IBAction)filterResult:(id)sender {
    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Pick Filter" rows:self.filterList initialSelection: self.selectedIndexes target:self successAction:@selector(animalWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:nil origin: self];
}


- (void)animalWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
    self.selectedIndexes = [selectedIndex intValue];
    NSLog(@"Selected");
}
```

Yes that's all. I've already included `ActionSheetPicker.h` file and as I said picker is working fine.

Finally here is error:

```
[MYYViewController successAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9032400
2012-12-24 12:14:45.488 Example[54268:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MYYViewController successAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9032400'
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: please add the actionsheet creating code

Comment: There is no more creating code for actionsheet, I've check sample app and added like that. And as I said picker is working well, listing as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks rather straight forward, you need to implement `successAction:` in your `MYYViewController` class, because the picker is not checking if it will respond or not and calling it directly.

Comment: Thank you but, I think that's wrong. Because `successAction:` is already implemented in `ActionSheetStringPicker.h` file. Why would I implement againt? Even I do, can you clarify that what would I write in that function?

Comment: @NewbieiOSDeveloper Methods are not implemented in a header file, they're declared. You have to ***implement*** them in the .m file. Headers don't contain actual code, just hints for the compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3, thanks. As Ismael said, there is a delegation error, successAction is already in `ActionSheetStringPicker.h`and I know .h files not contain any implementation so besides, `ActionSheetStringPicker.h` is including other .h files please have a look at: https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker/blob/master/ActionSheetPicker.h - Let me tidy up, successAction is a ActionSheetStringPicker's method but this code looking in MYYViewController. If this is true how can I change?